# Перестал работать selenium Chromedriver python

Tags: python, selenium

использую систему ubuntu 20.4. В питоне работала с selenium Chromedriver, однако после попытки установки Google-Search-API по следующей инструкции https://github.com/abenassi/Google-Search-API. Во время установки вышла следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR: tbselenium 0.5.3 has requirement selenium>=3.14, but you'll have selenium 2.53.6 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: selenium, unidecode, multidict, typing-extensions, yarl, vcrpy, Google-Search-API
  Attempting uninstall: selenium
    Found existing installation: selenium 3.141.0
    Uninstalling selenium-3.141.0:
      Successfully uninstalled selenium-3.141.0
Successfully installed Google-Search-API-1.1.14 multidict-5.1.0 selenium-2.53.6 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 unidecode-1.2.0 vcrpy-4.1.1 yarl-1.6.3
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

Дальше процесс установки завершился. Однако возникла проблема с запуском селениума
Код который я использую:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Ошибка которую я получаю:

```
  File "<ipython-input-75-f739fcfb02e1>", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

Помогите пожалуйста как это можно исправить?

Comment: Оффтоп: можно ли с тобой как-то связаться ?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, нужно было просто написать не

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

а

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Оставлю здесь мало ли может не я одна такая...